# Javascript error when using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, popup, scriptmanager

Note: the following is only an issue on the live server. In my local development, everything works fine.

I have a javascript function in my markup like so:

```
    function openNewWin(url) { 
        var x = window.open(url, 'mynewwin', 'width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0'); 
        x.focus();
    }
```

On a button click event, I call the following:

```
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "OpenWin", "openNewWin('" + url + "')",true);
```

This doesn't work and I get the following in chrome:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ScriptResource.axd:448
_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal ScriptResource.axd:448
_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal ScriptResource.axd:453
_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal ScriptResource.axd:453
_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal ScriptResource.axd:453
_ScriptLoader$_nextSession ScriptResource.axd:476
_ScriptLoader$_loadScriptsInternal ScriptResource.axd:462
_ScriptLoader$_nextSession ScriptResource.axd:476
_ScriptLoader$loadScripts ScriptResource.axd:372
PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted ScriptResource.axd:1480
$type.createDelegate ScriptResource.axd:628
$type.getHandler ScriptResource.axd:4338
raise ScriptResource.axd:7429
WebRequest$completed ScriptResource.axd:7433
Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange
```

and in IE I get:

```
Message: Expected ')'
Line: 1
Char: 51
Code: 0
URI: http://mysite.com/postage/printpostage.aspx
```

I can't figure what's wrong with my javascript. It works perfectly in development.

More details: I'm using ASP.NET WebForms. The button that the code is executed on is nested in an UpdatePanel.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit**:

I removed the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and just tried doing something simple on the button click but I get the same error. I guess it's something else that's causing it. How do I trouble shoot this?

**Edit #2:**

I started from scratch and it looks like it's any code with Scriptmanager.registerstartupscript. For example, I try it with the following and I get the same problem:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "AlertError", "alert('Error: " + ex.Message + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: Is your `openNewWin()` function defined before where your startup script is added to the page?

Comment: Yes, it is - I have it in my script tag in my html markup.

Comment: Does you url variable contain a single quote?

Comment: OK, this was the strangest thing. I don't know what I did that made it work but I removed the code, put it back in, used a new button, restarted my website and it worked.